# Where can I find .Net 4 installer?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0-beta-2

I want to download .Net 4, but I can't find it. Where can I find it for installing it offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [offline redistributable installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en) for just .NET 4.0 beta 2 (not VS2010).