# How can I manually uninstall .NET Framework Beta 2?

Tags: .net, uninstallation, .net-4.0-beta-2

Uninstalled VS2010 Beta 2.
Uninstalled .NET Framework 4 Extended Beta 2.

On attempting to uninstall .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Beta 2. I get

**Blocking Issues:
You must uninstall the .NET Framework 4 Extended Beta 2 before you uninstall the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Beta 2.**

On attempting to reinstall Framework 4 Beta 2 I get:

**Details:
Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 Beta 2 has already been installed on this computer.**

Please help!

Can I simply remove registry entries and the C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006 directory?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Delete all keys under: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4**
- Install http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DED875C8-FE5E-4CC9-B973-2171B61FE982&displaylang=en

  - First install crashes.
  - Reboot.
  - Second required repair.
  - Reboot.
  - Third completed.
  - Reboot.
- Uninstall .NET Framework 4 Extended Beta 2.
- Reboot.
- Uninstall .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Beta 2.
- Reboot.
- Try to convince boss you're a valuable member of his team.

Comment: Your link is dead...It's helpful when you post links to also say what it links to so another link can be found.

Comment: It was a link to offline redistributable installer for .NET 4.0 beta 2  (it was used in a [different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686629/where-i-found-dotnet-4-installer/1686651#1686651)).

Answer (score 1):

I just did this the other day. I used "Uninstall Programs" (formerly "Add/Remove Programs") in Control Panel to remove everything that had "beta 2" in the name.

Comment: That's what I did - however on uninstalling .NET Framework 4 Client Profile Beta 2 I get the error listed above. I believe my only option is to manually uninstall or format my hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing all keys under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4
I had to also remove this key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0
After doing this, the uninstaller for client profile beta 2 no longer complains.

Answer (score 1):

I had major trouble uninstalling the .net framework 4.0 (non-beta).  came across this app, which may help others:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx)

but it didn't work for me.  i've deleted all the registry keys as per the above, but that didn't work either...